# NextAuth with AWS Cognito - Redirecting users based on conditional API checks for user creation status

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, jwt, next-auth

I am using NextAuth along with AWS Cognito in my Next.js 13 application. I have set up the authentication flow successfully, but I'm facing an issue with redirecting users based on their organization creation status. I want to query my API when a user signs in to check if they have created an "organization". If they haven't, I want to redirect them to the /createOrganization route. Additionally, I want to enforce that users must have created an "organization" before they can access any other page, such as /dashboard.

Here's what I have done so far:

- Implemented NextAuth and AWS Cognito for authentication in my Next.js application.
- Configured the API call to check the organization creation status when a user signs in.
- Verified that the API gets triggered and returns an empty response for a new user.
  The problem I'm facing is that NextAuth is not redirecting the user to the /createOrganization route when the API call returns an empty response. Instead, the user remains on the same page.

Below is my code inside `/api/auth/[...nextauth].js/route.js`:

```
callbacks: {
      async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
        if (user) {
          try {
            const token = account.id_token;
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/organizationUser', {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                Accept: 'application/json',
              },
            });
      
            console.log("callback signIn token: ", token);
      
            if (response.ok) {
              const organizationUser = await response.json();

              if (organizationUser.length > 0) {
                // Store the dashboard URL in the user object for use in the redirect callback
                user.url = '/dashboard';
              } else {
                // Store the createOrganization URL in the user object for use in the redirect callback
                user.url = '/createOrganization';
              }
      
              return true;
            } else {
              throw new Error('Failed to fetch organization user');
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Failed to fetch organization user:', error);
            // Handle the error and return false to display a default error message
            return false;
          }
        }
        
        return true;
      },
      
      async redirect({ url, baseUrl, user }) {
        // Check if a URL was stored in the user object during signIn
        if (user && user.url) {
          return `${baseUrl}${user.url}`;
        }
      
        return url.startsWith('/') ? `${baseUrl}${url}` : url;
      },
      
      async session({ session, user, token }) {
        return session
      },
      async jwt({ user, token, account, profile }) {
        // if access token not in token then redirect to login
        if (!token.accessToken) {
          user.url = '/api/auth/signin';
        }


        if (account) {
          token.accessToken = account.id_token;
          token.id = profile.id
        }
        return token
      }
  }
```

I want the user to be authenticated before accessing the /createOrganization route so I am checking for that in the following code snippet for `/createOrganization/page.js`:

```
const CreateOrganizationPage = () => {
    const { data: session } = useSession({
        required: true,
        onUnauthenticated() {
            redirect("/api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=/createOrganization");
        }
    });
```